# Feature Selection for QSAR data in R for regression analysis

Tags: r, cross-validation, feature-selection

I am doing QSAR study for my data and after Running my structures through DRAGON software and getting the descriptors I am left with 383 desriptors (removing Constants and all ).
Now I want to perform Feature selection on my data. Where n=26 and p=383. So what approach should I follow ?
I have already done some step Wise regression analysis along with genetic algorithm studies to get R2 values of 0.831 for the 7 highly suitable descriptors.
But I wanted to try other approaches too such as Random Forest Method, PLS or PCA for my data. I am using R for the same. So any idea on the packages that can be used. I am already working with Caret and Boruta package.
Plus Any idea for packages for Cross validation studies. I need to perform LOOCV and Bootstrap.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: You have 26 observations and 383 potential features? That is a TALL task... Normally I will loop through a few variables at a time using feature selection on each subset and updating the winning variables as I go.

Comment: Thanks Jason. Even I did the same in my first approach. Broke the data set into many subsets and then worked for the feature selection thing. But I have heard that Random Forest and pls feature selection methods can work with this huge data set as well in one go. So I just wanted to know if anyone has any idea of how to implement that in R !

Answer (score 0):

If you use random forest or gradient boosting algorithms, they sometimes have a function already implemented that shows the "importance" score of each feature.

It is basically how often the algorithms selects a certain feature. You can run the algorithm with all you features and then look at this score. In e.g. XGBoost the features that were not used don't even appear in that list. So, you could use this to test which features are important or not.

Since you have many features you might run with random subsets of features first and subsequently kill the features that are not or only rarely used.

I find the term "importance" is a bit missleading here, as killing many "unimportant" features might result in quite a loss of performance. However, it is surely a good strategy to test for unusable features.